# In Firefox, how to find the bookmark count in a selected folder, including subfolders?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

If I use bookmark search, it searches all the bookmarks in every single folder and not just the selected one, so it is useless.

When I choose a folder and select everything in it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, it will only count the bookmarks directly in the folder, not including any subfolders.

What I need is the bookmark count in a folder including its subfolders, and I can't figure out how to find it.

Comment: Although it would be rather time consuming, you can always utilize the `Export Bookmarks to HTML` function to do this.  After you import them within Internet Explorer, you can right-click on the folder of your choice, select `Properties`, and the `Contains` value will show you the number of files/folders within your selected hierarchy.

Comment: this workaround is not practical at all since I need to do this on a fairly regular basis

Comment: It is an unusual workaround, but then again, needing *that* level of fidelity regarding the precise number of bookmarks within a specific subfolder hierarchy is also an unusual requirement.  I do it once-a-month to export computer-related bookmarks to an HTML file for another user, and once you become accustomed to the method it is relatively painless.  Regardless, hopefully someone else will chime in with a better solution.

Comment: "needing that level of fidelity regarding the precise number of bookmarks within a specific subfolder hierarchy is also an unusual requirement" - not really, it is the other way around - showing the number of bookmarks ignoring subfolders is unusual and mostly useless metric. In any other programs a similar count function would count subfolders. Take Windows Explorer for example - in folder properties it will count the files in all subfolders too.

Comment: Yes, but we aren't talking about `File Explorer` or any other program.  We are focusing our attention on Firefox.  Please, don't get me wrong: there is nothing unreasonable about your request.  On the other hand, I manage three Windows domains encompassing more than 10,000 Windows workstations that all have Firefox installed, and my team has never heard this particular request before.  As a result, it was safe to say that *"needing that level of fidelity regarding the precise number of Firefox bookmarks within a specific subfolder hierarchy is also an unusual requirement."*